# only one Node_modules folder for all

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

[image]
[image]
hello and today i want to know if i can have only one node_modules folder for all my node js bots, note they are not in app form just single files that use ..... = require('module'); my point is that i have easily more than 7 bots and i go back and forth improving them and maintaining the node_modules folder can be tedius, is there a way where i can have only one folder with all my modules and just do .... = require('path/to/node_modules/module');
or .... = require('path/to/node_modules/'); could someone please point me in the right direction, because when i update my code on my various bots i have to make sure the module is installed, can i have only one node_modules folder???

Comment: sorry this took a while i had to manualy type the addresses because its on my raspberry pi, so the folder that houses all my bot projects is called "/home/pi/Desktop/DESKTOP/Bots/" inside of the bot folder i have 9 different bots that all have a node_modules folder in them, "see what i mean", anyway i have just copied a node_modules folder form one of them bot projects to my "/home/pi/Desktop/DESKTOP" folder

Comment: i am a idiot..... sorry guys for wasting your time i used http://prntscr.com/g29wqb and it worked even though it wasnt before.... sorry guys

Comment: prntscr.com/g29zpe again.... only fs cannot be found please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of these different options:

1. You can put all your bot files in the same directory and run them all from that directory so all the modules installed in that directory can be used by all the bot files.
2. You can install all your modules globally.
3. You could make one shared directory where you installed all the modules and then explicitly point to that every time you want to load a module by referencing that path.  This seems less clean because every single user of a module has to know where to load it from.
4. For each module you want to use in a project, create symlinks to the place where the modules are actually installed.  This doesn't seem like it saves any work over just installing the modules again for each bot though.

Comment: i did try something like that but i got a problem, saying it could not locate 'fs' module even though it was recognising every other moudle

Comment: i did var module = require('path/to/node_module'); but i got that error i said above

Comment: @BenWall - You'd have to show us your code and describe the exact file hierarchy and desired filename to load for us to know what you were doing wrong.  It can work, though I think it's the least desirable option.

Comment: fourth option: use symlinks

Comment: @GottZ - Yes, symlinks could work to, but....  If you're going to symlink to every module you want to use, why not just install it locally.  The amount of disk space used is trivial.  I thought the OP is trying to have to avoid doing extra work for every single module that every single bot file is going to use which having to manually create a symlink does not do.  I will add the symlink option.

Comment: sorry this took a while i had to manualy type the addresses because its on my raspberry pi, so the folder that houses all my bot projects is called "/home/pi/Desktop/DESKTOP/Bots/" inside of the bot folder i have 9 different bots that all have a node_modules folder in them, "see what i mean", anyway i have just copied a node_modules folder form one of them bot projects to my "/home/pi/Desktop/DESKTOP" folder

Comment: @jfriend00 tbh i thought about simply throwing node_modules as symlink into each bot.
honestly i think it would be a better approach to just make a docker container that inherits node_modules and other assets from an earlier build image. (talking about overlay fs here)

Comment: and if someone really cares about such stuff he could even check out zfs deduplication or similar. (fs level dedupe)

Comment: i am a idiot..... sorry guys for wasting your time i used http://prntscr.com/g29wqb and it worked even though it wasnt before.... sorry guys

Comment: http://prntscr.com/g29zpe again.... only fs cannot be found please help

Answer (score 0):

In another file say `myLibs.js` you could do something like

```
module.exports = {
  lib1: require('lib1'),
  ...
  libn: require('libn')
}
```

then in the original file you would do

```
var myLibs=require('./myLibs.js');
```

and reference them by `myLibs.lib1...`

A little clunky, I know, but it should work.

Comment: where should i make the file "myLibs.js"

Comment: is it possible to have the node_modules folder and the myLibs file together and reference them like var myLibs=require('path/to/myLibs.js');

Comment: yes, that sounds like a good place to put it.  I usually have `libs` directory then use `var myLibs = require('./libs/myLibs.js')` or something similar.

Comment: sorry this took a while i had to manualy type the addresses because its on my raspberry pi, so the folder that houses all my bot projects is called "/home/pi/Desktop/DESKTOP/Bots/" inside of the bot folder i have 9 different bots that all have a node_modules folder in them, "see what i mean", anyway i have just copied a node_modules folder form one of them bot projects to my "/home/pi/Desktop/DESKTOP" folder

Comment: i am a idiot..... sorry guys for wasting your time i used http://prntscr.com/g29wqb and it worked even though it wasnt before.... sorry guys